# Why is objectlistview not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am trying to use object list view, and have followed everything. I have put the dll into my references, and have gone as far as putting it in my debug, and release folder.

The problem I am having is that it keeps giving me this error:

[image]

Is there anything I am doing that is wrong?

Comment: Do you have the `using BrightIdeasSoftware;` statement in your code?

Comment: When I try to do that, intellisense pops up, but it does not give me an option for BrightIdeasSoftware....

Comment: BTW: I am smart enough to know that, but thanks for trying :D

Comment: Occam's Razor - sometimes it's this simple stuff :)  Is the assembly you're referencing a .NET assembly?  Do you have the right assembly/namespace name?

Comment: I think it is a .NET assembly. And there is no other option in intellisense that would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this [discussion thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812922/thread/c5f7537c).

Someone said they checked the FAQ and subsequently "changed the target to the full profile." It sounds like if your project is built against a client profile, you could run into this issue. I haven't downloaded the `ObjectListView` source myself and tried to build it to see if that's actually the case.

Check that your project is building against the full .NET framework, and not a "client profile". I use VS2012 now, which creates new projects with the full profile already set. But if you happen to be using VS2010, it created new projects with a target framework of "client profile" by default.

[image]

Comment: I would check this.  It gets me all the time when making scratch projects.